# Tricky sass selector nesting

Tags: css, sass, macos-darkmode

I'm currently adding a dark mode to a site of mine.  The change is all handled via a script and takes into account the users preference and also the current appearance of their machine. I basically end up with a 'dark' class on `<body>` if in dark mode otherwise nothing.

Everything is working perfectly but on one element I need to change the background image based on this but i'm encountering a problem because my top level selector is already based on body.

Here's my code:

```
.page-home {
  .home-intro__caricature {
    @include ratio-box(100%);
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--main-background-color);
    background-image: url('../src/svgs/caricature.svg'), url('../src/svgs/pattern-light.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: center bottom, center center;
    background-size: contain, auto;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;

    &.dark {
      background-image: url('../src/svgs/caricature.svg'), url('../src/svgs/pattern-dark.svg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
      background-position: center bottom, center center;
      background-size: contain, auto;
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is that `.page-home` is a class on `<body>` and `.dark` also needs to be so.   How can I construct the selector so that `.dark` is added onto the selector for `body`?

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question properly, the following should work.

There's also no need to reiterate the other background properties.

```
.page-home {
  .home-intro__caricature {
    @include ratio-box(100%);
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--main-background-color);
    background-image: url('../src/svgs/caricature.svg'), url('../src/svgs/pattern-light.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: center bottom, center center;
    background-size: contain, auto;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }

  &.dark {
    .home-intro__caricature {
      background-image: url('../src/svgs/caricature.svg'), url('../src/svgs/pattern-dark.svg');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have clarified.  I realise I could split it out a bit like that.  I was trying to see if there would be solution without repeating part of the selector a little.  Just to keep things a little more concise.  The other properties werent meant to be there.  Left them in after copy pasting. Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't think there's a better SASS solution to be honest. You could, of course, make the SASS more concise by adding a class to the child element with JavaScript.

Comment: Yeh, i couldn't think of one, hence my post.  I could add a class via JS but i'll most likely have a similar issue in a couple of places so i don't think i'll go that route.  I'll go with the split route like you suggested i think.  Thanks